# Android: NullPointerException using getCacheDir()

Tags: android, caching, nullpointerexception

I'm building an app that allows users to record and upload <30 second sounds, and I'm trying to figure out a way to temporarily store the sound on the device (so that the user can review it, etc) until it is uploaded to the server. I thought using getCacheDir() for the filepath should be the solution, but I keep getting an NPE no matter what form of it I try. Other people have run into this issue and asked about it on SO but never really gotten a satisfactory answer or workaround. Any suggestions for how to fix it or an alternative temp storage method? My app has a minimum SDK of Android 2.0 so I can't use getExternalCacheDir().

For context, here is my declaration:

```
Context context;    
private String fileName = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/wavesaudio/" + "temp" +".3gp";
```

And usage:

```
public void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recordTime = 0;
```

Similar usage for playback. The error message I get says it's an NPE and points to the exact line where the fileName string is declared.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably `context` is `null`

Comment: Use `context = getApplicationContext();` inside onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `context` before you have assigned it a value.

You should probably make the assignment to `filename` in your [Activity.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method, as in:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = this; // "context" may not be needed

    // Note: you don't need to use "context" here, since the Activity is itself a Context.
    fileName = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/wavesaudio/" + "temp" +".3gp";

    // Rest of your onCreate() code ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm - how does one assign a value to a context declaration? Context context = getApplicationContext() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So, the class that this is stored in is a helper class AudioRecorder.java, so there is no onCreate method. It just contains all the methods for recording/playback. Does this mean I should declare the fileName in the class that actually utilizes AudioRecorder?

Comment: You can pass a `Context` to the helper when you construct it, and the constructor can assign the value to `filename`. But, yes, it is probably better to just pass in the `filename`.

Comment: I had to go through and reconfigure some of my other classes that used it, but it did solve the getCacheDir error! Thank you, @cybersam!

Answer (score 0):

You must assign your fileName in onCreate() of your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private String fileName;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fileName = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/wavesaudio/" + "temp" +".3gp";
```